# How to connect to Redmine from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, redmine, mylyn, redmine-plugins

I have setup environment like this:

Redmine side:

```
Redmine: 2.2.0.stable (BitNami Windows version)
Ruby: 1.9.3
Rails: 3.2.9
Environment: production
redmine_mylyn_connector plugin: 2.8.2.stable
```

Eclipse side:

```
JavaEE IDE Juno Windows version
Mylyn Connector Redmine: 0.3.7.20120300721
```

I tried to add a new task repository and chose `Redmine`, however, after I finished the settings and clicked "`Validate Settings`", immediately I got a "`Unexpected status code - 404`" error message. So I am wondering how to get this work. I saw some people were talking about using generic web connector, but it seems from an old project and I couldn't find it anymore.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

For Juno, these instructions worked for me: http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_Mylyn#Using-the-generic-web-repository-connector

However, it looks like the Mylyn Incubator repository has gone away so that may no longer be viable.

Answer (score 1):

A version exist at this url :

http://danmunn.github.io/redmine_mylyn_connector/

But it seems it's not working with eclipse juno 4.2